# How to skip column in a Google sheet reference range

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am using App Script with Google sheet. In my code.gs file - I have created function that references a google sheet and the range. Is there to skip a column when referencing a range? Please check the function below.

I tried to use the following reference function but it does not work

```
'Data!A:A,C:C,E:E',
```

```
function globalVar(){ 
  var varArray = {
    spreadsheetId   : 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',                                   
    xRange          : 'Data!A:A,C:C,E:E',                        
    yRange          : 'Board!A2:B',                           
    lastCol         : 'L',                                            
    sheetID         : '0'                                             
  };
  return varArray;
}
```

Comment: Get ask the data and filter in only what's required using [Array.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

Comment: Array = sh.getRange("A1:E" + sh.getLastRow()).getValues().Use map to filter the columns Array.map([a,,c,,e] => [a,c,e]);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to use Pivot table to ignore the columns.